# Unsupported Server Component type: undefined / next js 13

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

I ran into some weird behavior in Next js 13 while trying to do a simple action.
I have prepared the most simple example showing the problem. I hope you can help me figure out why this is happening.

There are 3 components.

**page:**

```
import {Container} from '../components/Container'
export default function index() {
  return (
    <Container>
        <Container.Window>
            <h1>12345</h1>
        </Container.Window>
    </Container>
  )
}
```

**Container:**

```
'use client';
import { Window } from './Window';

export const Container = ({ children }) => {
  return children;
};

Container.Window = Window;
```

**Window:**

```
"use client";
export const Window = ({children})=>{
  return children
}
```

**Page server component. The Container and Window components are client-side. Container imports and exports Window.**

I am getting this error:

> "Unsupported Server Component type: undefined"

- **Import the Window component separately.**
  Works, no errors
- **Make the Container component a server component.**
  Works, no errors
- **Make the page component client-side.**
  Works, no errors

But I think the first option is the most convenient. Would love to make it work

https://stackblitz.com/edit/nextjs-fwuztm?file=app%2Fpage.js,components%2FContainer.js,components%2FWindow.js - example

Answer (score 17):

I had the same issue. I was able to fix by changing the named export to a default export, and importing without the braces.

Try changing:

```
export const Window = ({children})=>{
```

to

```
const Window = ({children})=>{
...
}
export default Window;
```

Hopin that helps!

Comment: I made this change and it worked. But... why?? So confused.

Comment: @JoshuaDance Did you find any answer for why exporting explicitly works. I myself did ran into the same situation in nextjs

Comment: @NishantSalode never figured it out. I just do it like the above now.

Answer (score 4):

### Update (for named imports)

As per [Jason Frank](https://stackoverflow.com/users/718325/jason-frank)'s comments, you can keep the `'use client'` at the component level without the need to mark all components as client side in the `index.ts`. This allows you to keep using named imports whilst keeping a folder of mixed server/client components.

```
// Client Side Component
'use client'

export default function ClientCard() {
  return <p>client side card here</p>
}
```

```
// Server Side Component
export default function ServerCard() {
  return <p>server side card here</p>
}
```

```
// index.ts
export { default as ClientCard } from './client-card';
export { default as ServerCard } from './server-card';
```

---

Not too sure if this is related but ran into a similar issue.

```
'use client'

export function Card() {
  return <p>card here</p>
}
```

```
// index.ts
export * from './card'
```

The above threw errors when attempting to import via `import { Card } from './card`.

Adding `'use client'` to the `index.ts` seemed to fix the issue.

```
// index.ts - FIXED
'use client'

export * from './card'
```

Comment: While this approach did solve the error (in my monorepo), my testing showed that it also made (*all*) the components exported from the `index.ts` file *client* components.

Comment: Unfortunately, that is the case. I have ended up separating my server and client components into separate folders. I don't mind it as it means I'm consciously keeping the client/server logic separate. I much prefer the named exports over a default export so I'll be sticking with this for now.

Comment: I was able create a named-export approach at the `index.ts` level by writing each export line there like:
`export { default as Anchor } from "./Anchor";`
So for consuming projects in my monorepo, they still use named imports like:
`import { Anchor } from "ui" // "ui" is a package in my monorepo`

Answer (score 2):

If you are exporting your component as default export and are importing your component as a named export or vice versa, this could also be the scenario where the problem occurs

Importing and Exporting error like this:

exported component:

```
export default function ExportedComp() {
//logic
}
```

Page where you import:

```
import {ExportedComp} from 'pathname'
```

Or vice versa!

Answer (score 1):

## This issue portrayed with external/component library

I ran into this issue as well, my problem was the way I was exporting / importing.

##### ***for reference***...

> This is for a react component library. I was receiving your same error when importing my component from the package in my next.js application.

##### Structure of the library

```
├── src
│   ├── components
│   │   ├── MyComponentName
│   │   │   ├── MyComponentName.tsx
│   │   │   ├── ...
│   │   │   ├── index.ts
│   │   ├── index.ts
│   ├── ...
│   ├── index.ts
├── ...
```

---

##### `MyComponentName.tsx`

```
const MyComponentName () => {

    return <>
    /* stuff */
    </>
};

export default MyComponentName; /* make sure to default export initially */
```

##### `MyComponentName/index.ts`

```
import MyComponentName from "./MyComponentName"; // import the component from the component file

export default MyComponentName; // export default
```

##### `components/index.ts`

```
export { default as MyComponentName } from "./MyComponentName";
```

#### Lastly...

##### `src/index.ts`

```
export { MyComponentName } from "./components";
```

---

Then, to import from the package:

```
import { MyComponentName } from "@clxrityy/my-component-library";
```

---

I know this particular example seems like an overly complex structure of imports/exports, but it's necessary for my purposes. I hope this can help anyone who is running into a similar issue with these circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

I had this return jsx:

```
return <>{product && <ProductView product={product} />}</>;
```

it turns out that importing one component inside `ProductView` was from the wrong path.