# Next13 app folder not render html in page source

Tags: next.js, seo, server-side-rendering, next.js13, react-server-components

i've been testing Nextjs beta for a while now but i'm noticing that the page-source it's always empty no matter what.

Example :

```js
import VisitProvider from "./(components)/VisitProvider";
import Visit from "./(components)/Visit";
import FlightSearcherWrapper from "./(components)/FlightSearcherWrapper";
import { headers } from "next/headers";
import { Suspense } from "react";
import ServerComponent from "./(components)/ServerComponent";

const Page = () => {
  const headersList = headers();
  const userAgent = headersList.get("user-agent");
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Test</h1>
      <ServerComponent />
      <VisitProvider userAgent={userAgent}>
        <Suspense fallback={<div>Suspending..</div>}>
          <Visit />
        </Suspense>
        <FlightSearcherWrapper />
      </VisitProvider>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Page;
```

Output on the pagesource :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html id="__next_error__">
  <head>
    <link rel="preload" as="script" href="/_next/static/chunks/polyfills.js" />
    <script src="/_next/static/chunks/polyfills.js" nomodule=""></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="/_next/static/chunks/webpack.js" async=""></script>
    <script src="/_next/static/chunks/main-app.js" async=""></script>
  </body>
</html>
<script>
  (self.__next_f = self.__next_f || []).push([0]);
</script>
<script>
  self.__next_f.push([1, '0:"$L1"\n']);
</script>
<script>
  self.__next_f.push([
    1,
    '2:I{"id":"(app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/app-router.js","name":"","chunks":["app-client-internals:app-client-internals"],"async":false}\n4:I{"id":"(app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/error-boundary.js","name":"","chunks":["app-client-internals:app-client-internals"],"async":false}\n5:I{"id":"(app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/layout-router.js","name":"","chunks":["app-client-internals:app-client-internals"],"async":false}\n6:I{"id":"(app-client)',
  ]);
</script>
<script>
  self.__next_f.push([
    1,
    '/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/render-from-template-context.js","name":"","chunks":["app-client-internals:app-client-internals"],"async":false}\n7:I{"id":"(app-client)/./app/test/(components)/VisitProvider.js","name":"","chunks":["app/test/page:app/test/page"],"async":false}\n8:"$Sreact.suspense"\n9:I{"id":"(app-client)/./app/test/(components)/Visit.js","name":"","chunks":["app/test/page:app/test/page"],"async":false}\na:I{"id":"(app-client)/./app/test/(components)/FlightSearcherWrapper.js","name":',
  ]);
</script>
<script>
  self.__next_f.push([
    1,
    '"","chunks":["app/test/page:app/test/page"],"async":false}\n',
  ]);
</script>
<script>
  self.__next_f.push([
    1,
    '1:["$","$L2",null,{"assetPrefix":"","initialCanonicalUrl":"/test","initialTree":["",{"children":["test",{"children":["",{}]},null,null,true]}],"initialHead":["$L3",[["$","title",null,{}],["$","meta",null,{"content":"width=device-width, initial-scale=1","name":"viewport"}],["$","link",null,{"rel":"icon","href":"/favicon.ico"}]]],"globalErrorComponent":"$4","children":["$","$L5",null,{"parallelRouterKey":"children","segmentPath":["children"],"hasLoading":false,"template":["$","$L6",null,{}],"childProp":{"current":[["$","html",null,{"children":[["$","head",null,{}],["$","body",null,{"children":["$","$L5",null,{"parallelRouterKey":"children","segmentPath":["children","test","children"],"hasLoading":false,"template":["$","$L6",null,{}],"notFound":[["$","title",null,{"children":"404: This page could not be found."}],["$","div",null,{"style":{"fontFamily":"system-ui,\\"Segoe UI\\",Roboto,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif,\\"Apple Color Emoji\\",\\"Segoe UI Emoji\\"","height":"100vh","textAlign":"center","display":"flex","flexDirection":"column","alignItems":"center","justifyContent":"center"},"children":["$","div",null,{"children":[["$","style",null,{"dangerouslySetInnerHTML":{"__html":"body{color:#000;background:#fff;margin:0}.next-error-h1{border-right:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.3)}@media (prefers-color-scheme:dark){body{color:#fff;background:#000}.next-error-h1{border-right:1px solid rgba(255,255,255,.3)}}"}}],["$","h1",null,{"className":"next-error-h1","style":{"display":"inline-block","margin":"0 20px 0 0","padding":"0 23px 0 0","fontSize":24,"fontWeight":500,"verticalAlign":"top","lineHeight":"49px"},"children":"404"}],["$","div",null,{"style":{"display":"inline-block"},"children":["$","h2",null,{"style":{"fontSize":14,"fontWeight":400,"lineHeight":"49px","margin":0},"children":"This page could not be found."}]}]]}]}]],"childProp":{"current":[["$","div",null,{"children":[["$","a",null,{"href":"/","children":"This is a server component"}],["$","$L7",null,{"userAgent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/109.0.0.0 Safari/537.36","children":[["$","$8",null,{"fallback":["$","div",null,{"children":"Suspending.."}],"children":["$","$L9",null,{}]}],["$","$La",null,{}]]}]]}],null,null,[]],"segment":""}}]}]]}],null,null,[]],"segment":"test"}}]}]\n',
  ]);
</script>
<script>
  self.__next_f.push([
    1,
    '3:[[["$","meta",null,{"charSet":"utf-8"}],null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,["$","meta",null,{"name":"viewport","content":"width=device-width, initial-scale=1"}],null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,[]],[null,null,null,null],null,null,[null,null,null,null,null],null,null,null,null,null]\n',
  ]);
</script>
```

So, not only the server component is just streamed as JSON (i thought should be rendered on the server and sent as html ), but also the Visit component ( which is client and in the documentation it's written that it would be prerendered on the server as well )but most surpisingly the  tag is not there in the page source.
Can someone clarify this ?
I'm concerned about SEO here.

Comment: A reproducible environment is necessary. Next.js does render HTML. However, there are so many possible reasons for this: some codes might be hindering statically rendering pages from higher order components(_document.jsx, _app.jsx), router setting is wrong, and dev vs prod render difference(next.js uses slightly different method for dev and prod for hot-reloading)...without having an access to the rest of the environment, it's really hard to tell what's wrong.

Answer (score 4):

TL:DR: Checkout [NextJS: Entire page deopted into client-side rendering](https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/deopted-into-client-rendering).

---

Ran into a similar issue. I was importing client components without using `Suspense`. Running in dev mode didnt seem to log anything or complain, but running a build and then starting the build server I got a nice error and link to [this page](https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/deopted-into-client-rendering) about deopting into client-side rendering.

I'd also double check your client only components are marked as `'use client'` (including any intermediate `index` files that may import/export the components - [see this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75261466/unsupported-server-component-type-undefined-next-js-13/75955626#75955626) for more info about import/exporting).

If you are using `useSearchParams`, double check the component is marked as client only. When you're referencing the component from a server context, wrap it in a React `Suspense` component (as outlined in the official [Next docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/deopted-into-client-rendering)).

Your `page.tsx` here looks okay, do you have a `layout.tsx` too? Thats where my issues were. If you're attempting to import client-only analytics tracking too, you'll need to wrap that in `Suspense`.

Comment: Wow, this is a crazy gottcha! Wrapping my GA component with suspense solved the issue. Phew.