next-intl getMessageFallback in Client Component throws "Functions cannot be passed directly" error
I'm using next-intl in my Next.js 14 app to handle localization.
I want to implement a fallback method for missing translations, so that if a translation like AssetDescriptions.NOT_EXISTS_TEST is not available, it should return NOT_EXISTS_TEST as value.
According to the documentation, I should be able to pass onError and getMessageFallback to the NextIntlClientProvider to customize how missing translations and errors are handled.
This is my code src/app/[locale]/layout.js:
import { NextIntlClientProvider, useMessages, IntlErrorCode } from "next-intl";

function getMessageFallback({ namespace, key, error }) {
  const path = [namespace, key].filter((part) => part != null).join(".");

  if (error.code === IntlErrorCode.MISSING_MESSAGE) {
    return path + " is not yet translated";
  } else {
    return "Dear developer, please fix this message: " + path;
  }
}

export default function LocaleLayout({ children, params }) {
  const { locale } = params;
  const messages = useMessages();

  return (
    <NextIntlClientProvider
      locale={locale}
      messages={messages}
      getMessageFallback={getMessageFallback}
    >
      {children}
    </NextIntlClientProvider>
  );
}

Error:
Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: Functions cannot be passed directly to Client Components unless you explicitly expose it by marking it with "use server". Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it.
  <... locale="it" now={Date} timeZone=... messages=... getMessageFallback={function getMessageFallback} children=...>
                   


I think you should be using IntlProvider because NextIntlClientProvider is a client component and data passed in props to a client component must be serializable but functions are not serializable
import { IntlProvider } from "next-intl";

this is its type:
function IntlProvider(
             { children, defaultTranslationValues, formats, getMessageFallback, locale, messages, now, onError, timeZone }
                                                                               :Props): React.JSX.Element

see it accepts getMessageFallback:
getMessageFallback?(info: {
        error: IntlError;
        key: string;
        namespace?: string;
    }): string;


Thanks but I tried using IntlProvider as you recommended, but I'm facing the following error:
Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: Unsupported Server Component type: undefined
It seems that IntlProvider is not compatible in this context. Moreover, the next-intl documentation suggests using NextIntlClientProvider, which does accept the same props as IntlProvider, including getMessageFallback.
The issue seems to be related to passing non-serializable functions to client-side components in Next.js. Do you have any other suggestions on how I can resolve this?

docs: https://next-intl-docs.vercel.app/docs/getting-started/app-router/with-i18n-routing

in the above docs link, they do not pass  getMessageFallback because you cannot. the exacmple code on your post is faulty, you should be raising issue on thier github. as its  name says it is a client component provider and yet they are passing a function as a prop

regarding the error message on using IntlProvider, can you read this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75261466/unsupported-server-component-type-undefined-next-js-13

Thanks! I made progress, but I'm still stuck on passing messages to NextIntlClientProvider. Here's what I have:
app/layout.js:
const messages = useMessages();
return (

{children}

);
app/[locale]/layout.js:
const messages = useMessages();
return (

{children}

);
I keep getting MISSING_MESSAGE errors. Any ideas on how to pass messages properly?

adding formatted code here: https://pastebin.com/e1QXNAFT

any idea? thanks

what is the issue passing messages to NextIntlClientProvider now

It work, but I can't pass Messages properly.
